# capturing repeating groups with reg ex in python

Tags: python, regex

Ex. "steve && chris || joe && george"

```
Group[0] = steve && chris 
Group[1] = joe && george
```

I can find the first group (.*?)([|]{2}) but how can find the next group.

keep in mind i want it to be dynamic. String will grow in the same pattern. 
For Ex.

```
"steve && chris || joe && george || sep && geo"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the best way is to just use the Python split function:

```
s = 'steve && chris || joe && george'
s.split(' || ')  # returns ['steve && chris', 'joe && george']
```

However, to use a regex, you could do the following:

```
import re
# group all strings separated by `|` and at least length 1
arr = re.findall('[^|]{1,}', "steve && chris || joe && george || sep && geo")
print(arr)  # ['steve && chris ', ' joe && george ', ' sep && geo']
```

Answer (score 3):

A non Regex solution can be using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
>>> s = "steve && chris || joe && george"
>>> tmp = s.split('||')
>>> groups = map(str.strip,tmp)
>>> groups
['steve && chris', 'joe && george']
```

The [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is used here to cleanse the groups

and it is dynamic also

```
>>> s =  "steve && chris || joe && george || sep && geo"
>>> tmp = s.split('||')
>>> groups = map(str.strip,tmp)
>>> groups
['steve && chris', 'joe && george', 'sep && geo']
```

Do note that basic string functions work out faster than RegEx solutions

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use `regex`, you can use the following:

```
(\w*\ ?&&\ ?\w*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kO7oY2/1)

You can also use python `split` function for this.